# PayPal Access/Bearer token

Tags: paypal, oauth-2.0, paypal-sandbox, paypal-rest-sdk

How to get **Access/Bearer** Token from PayPal **https://api-m.paypal.com/v1/oauth2/token** API call using Live PayPal ClientID and Secret Key.

I have used below setup before callling API in Postman

Basic Auth type.
Body tab = x-www-form-urlencoded.
grant_type = client_credentials

I am getting below response when calling above API with Live ClientID and Secret Key using **Postman**

***{
"error": "invalid_client",
"error_description": "Client Authentication failed"
}***

And When using **SandBox** api **https://api-m.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/oauth2/token** with Live CliendID and Secret Key it generates token but not authenticated when calling with other Live PayPal **APIs** to get records.

Answer (score 0):

> When using SandBox api https://api-m.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/oauth2/token with Live CliendID and Secret Key it generates token

The *only* way to receive a token from api-m.sandbox.paypal.com is if you are *actually* using a **sandbox** Client ID and secret. There is no other possible way, the sandbox environment is completely separate from live.

Since your question is about how to obtain a live token from api-m.paypal.com , you must instead use a Client ID and secret from the "Live" tab of a REST API app in [developer.paypal.com](https://www.paypal.com/signin?intent=developer&returnUri=https%3A%2F%2Fdeveloper.paypal.com%2Fdeveloper%2Fapplications%2F). (Clearly you are not using the correct credentials if you think the same ones work for sandbox.)

If you still think you are, what is the actual live Client ID you are using? Update your question with this information, and test it at https://developer.paypal.com/demo/checkout/#/pattern/client -- a live Client ID will necessarily lead to a live paypal.com checkout.